# symfony migration create table and insert record

Tags: symfony1, migration

I want to create a new table and then insert a specific record in a symfony 1.4 project. I can do the data insert manually, but I would like to make use of the migration infrastructure so that when different existing instances are upgraded this row will be created when the migrations are run.

Here is the sequence of migrations:

1. Create a new table `email`.
2. Insert a row into the table `email`.

(Note that these are two *separate* consecutive migrations.)

The problem is that in this migration there is no chance to generate the base model classes, so attempting to insert the row using the normal Doctrine commands will fail.

I could use a naked SQL INSERT commands, but that seems like an admission of defeat. Is there another, more Doctrine-friendly way to do the data insert?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to do migrations. Do the following :

- Update your schema.yml to include the new table
- Create a new task or fixture file with the new entry
- Run `symfony doctrine:generate-migrations-diff` - this will create the migration file
- Run `symfony doctrine:build --all-classes --and-migrate`

The last line will update the Database - ie create the new table and also create the base model classes. Here are the options (related to classes on the `build` command)

```
 --all-classes      Build all classes
 --model            Build model classes
 --forms            Build form classes
 --filters          Build filter classes
```

The just run the task to insert the new DB entry or use the new fixtures (using `symfony doctrine:data-load --append <filename>`) file to create the entry in the DB.

Comment: Let's say you have two migrations: migration 1 creates the table and then migration 2 inserts the data. If you run `symfony doctrine:build --all-classes --and-migrate` will the classes be built from migration 1 _before_ migration 2 is run? If not, then your method will not work (at least in this circumstance).

Comment: @rlandster, the doctrine:build --all-classes (or its more specific variant options) task works by looking at the current schema. It is oblivious to the migration classes and to which migration version is current.  Therefore, as long as you have updated to the new schema (containing your new email model/table) before running the migration it should work fine.

Comment: @jweible, this implies that you cannot run a very long series of migrations in one go without running into problems, since it is quite likely that some of your early migrations would not be compatible with the current `schema.yml`. For example, imagine changing the name of a table or dropping a column.

Comment: @rlandster.  You can have a very long series of migrations run successfully in one batch, if they're only making schema changes even changing tables or dropping columns.  As you imply, it's only if they're also running database record queries/updates then they might fail if they referred to a table or field that differs from those defined by your doctrine classes.